# запуск функции, имя которой находится в переменной

Tags: javascript

запуск функции, имя которой находится в переменной.
Например:

```
var f_name = 'f_start';
```

И нужно запустить функцию с именем f_start. Это выполнимая задача?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function f_start(){
    alert('UpS!');
}

var f_name = 'f_start';
window[f_name]();
// можно еще так, как показано ниже, НО не советую, т.к. **eval === evil**
//eval(f_name)();
```

Comment: >eval === evil

замечательно сказано)))

Comment: >eval === evil

далеко не всегда, eval - это фитча, которой надо уметь пользоваться